# Google Maps API v3 / MVC 4 - geocoding an address that's passed to a (partial view) modal window in an MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of search results. Beside each result is a button that when clicked launches a partial view housing a Bootstrap modal.

The modal is strongly typed, the object passed in represents a residential property which has an address. The address is displayed in the modal header.

I'm trying to get the address and pass it to a JS function that will geocode it and display it on a tab in the modal.

What I've tried:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 id="myModalLabel" data-id="@Model.Address.Line1,@if (Model.Address.Line2 != null)
    { @Model.Address.Line2; },@Model.Address.TownCity,@Model.Address.County">
        // display the address
    </h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">map canvas</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
```

JS as end of partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
initialize();

var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = $('#myModalLabel').attr('data-id');
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

So I've tried to add `data-id` attribute to the the modal label that displays the address and then select that in the `codeAddress()` function.

The default map with the hard coded latlng displays, but the no geocoding is happening. Can someone point me in the right direction? Perhaps giving a more elegant way of getting the address from the model and passing it to `codeAddress()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using code from google's tutorials and there they were calling `codeAddress()` in a button click event. I wasn't actually calling `codeAddress()`.

Adding `codeAddress()` after `initialize()` has resolved the issue.